# Django - list items based on a foreign key

Tags: python, django

I am a new to python, Django (and programming in general). I have spend over 10 hours on this problem, but I seem to be missing something.

I have two models in Django - articles and categories, and I am using ListView and DetailsView in my views.py file. On the articles_details page, I am trying to list all the articles that are in the same category as the current article.

I have tried a million things, but to no avail. I am thinking that I could define a function using __exact to filter the categories database, based on the current value of articles.category (the category of the current article). I am not sure how to do so, though, and how to call such a function in my template.

Could someone please assist? Thank you, in advance.

P.S.: Not sure if part of the problem is using ListView and DetailsView. Here is my code:

Views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from web import models
from web.models import Main, Series_rh, Articles_rh
from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView,ListView,DetailView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'web/index.html'

class CategoriesView(ListView):
    model = models.Series_rh
    template_name = 'web/series.html'
    context_object_name = 'Categories_rh_list'

class CategoriesView(DetailView):
    model = models.Series_rh
    template_name = 'web/series.html'
    context_object_name = 'Categories_rh_details'

class ArticlesListView(ListView):
    model = models.Articles_rh
    template_name = 'web/articles-list.html'
    context_object_name = 'Artciles_rh_list'

class ArticlesDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Articles_rh
    template_name = 'web/articles-details.html'
    context_object_name = 'Articles_rh_details'
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

    class Categories_rh(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        description = models.TextField()
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Articles_rh(models.Model):
        para_one = models.TextField()
        para_two = models.TextField()
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/media/')
        featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories_rh, on`_delete='models.SET_NULL', blank=True, null=True, rela`ted_name='categories_for_articles')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: You don't seem to have shown what you have tried.

Comment: post your web/articles-details.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do something like this in your **web/articles-details.html** file:

```
{% for article in Articles_rh_details.categories.categories_for_articles.all %}
  <p>{{ article.para_one }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, why is that:

`Articles_rh_details` is how you named your `Articles_rh` model instance in the `ArticlesDetailView`, via the `context_object_name` attribute.

From that, we can access the `Articles_rh`'s property `categories`, which is your relationship with the `Categories_rh` model.

In this relationship, you set the `related_name` attribute to `categories_for_articles`. This is actually the name of the reverse relationship of *all articles associated with this particular category*.

Since it will return a `QuerySet`, we have either to call the `all()` method, or `filter()`, or `order_by()`, etc. But, since we are in the template, not much we can do but call the `all()` method.

The final result will be a list of all articles associated with this category.

I would recommend you to renamed this reverse relationship (the `related_name`) to just `articles` instead of `categories_for_articles`. It will read more natural. Also the `categories` relationship would read more natural if it was `category` (singular) instead, since the relationship is with only one category. And finally, the `context_object_name` could be just `article` instead. That way you would access the desired group of articles like this:

```
{% for related_article in article.category.articles.all %}
    {{ related_article.para_one }}
{% endfor %}
```

Just some general advices to improve the readability of your code. :-)

Comment: Wow! Thank you, Victor. Not only that worked exactly the way it was supposed to, your explanation was fabulous. I have a much clearer understanding of the concept now. I also took your advice on renaming for better readability.